# Continuous deployment with multiple website projects in solution

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2012, continuous-integration, msdeploy, continuous-deployment

We are using VS2012 and have a solution with 4 website projects in it. We have added the following MSBuild arguments to our Continuous Integration msbuild arguments:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True
/P:Configuration=Testing
/p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish
/p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSvc
/p:CreatePackageOnPublish=False
/p:DeployIisAppPath="{test}"
/p:SkipExtraFilesOnServer=true
/p:MsDeployServiceUrl={test}/MsDeploy.axd
/P:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True
/p:username={username}
/p:password={password}
```

When we do a check in and the continuous integrations runs, it's publishes all 4 websites to the same directory. How do we specify which project belongs to which IIS application?

We have tried moving the settings into the csproj as suggested on [How to tell TFS to deploy multiple webapps containing in one solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457108/how-to-tell-tfs-to-deploy-multiple-webapps-containing-in-one-solution) After making the changes, the check in worked but it didn't publish.

Comment: Would it not be better to split into 4 sln one per website?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's deploying to the same site because you are passing `DeployIisAppPath` in at the command line.

You can create a publish profile in each web application with the same name (eg. `Stage.pubxml`), each containing a differen `DeployIisAppPath` value. When you deploy, you can specify `/p:PublishProfile=Stage` and it will use the settings from that profile *for each specific project*.

If you want to specify properties like `SkipExtraFilesOnServer` and `MsDeployServiceUrl` from the command line, just remove them from your publish profiles.

Comment: @ Michael @Richard Szalay is there some condition in which only the first compiled project is taking the publish profile? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38306581/msbuild-publish-profile-not-being-passed-to-second-web-project-for-solution-with