# TFS Build deployment with multiple sites

Tags: .net, tfs, msbuild, tfs-2015

To Build and publish Solution on-premise for 2(multiple) sites we created TFS 2015 Build that has separate build steps. Those Builds just differ by `MSBuild` `/p:DeployIisAppPath` arguments. But when this Build runs it creates 2 Deployment packages that would be deployed to the same site, which can be confirmed by looking at `SetParameters.xml` file. Is there any way to overcome this problem and setup on-premise build so that each Package gets Deployed to each respective site?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the publishing settings as part of the project file and not part of the TFS build definition. All the MSBuild paramaters can be moved inside the csproj. Check the solutions at links below:

[How to tell TFS to deploy multiple webapps containing in one solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457108/how-to-tell-tfs-to-deploy-multiple-webapps-containing-in-one-solution)

[WebDeploy to deploy multiple web sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832154/webdeploy-to-deploy-multiple-web-sites)